# Test case skipped with Selenium using TestNG framework

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, testng

I am using Selenium WebDriver with TestNG framework for running test suite on Windows
The problem is that I have only test case get skipped in between where I believe driver becomes unresponsive. However the logs failed to capture any details why the test cases are getting skipped.

I run the sample code to just open google.com in and that works, Only this code is not working:giving bellow. so it means drivers and setup is fine, Only having problem with this code.

```
package com.qa.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import test.v6.B;

public class FridayTaskTesting {

    @Test
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\\\new\\\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("https://hello.friday.de/quote/selectPrecondition");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      Thread.sleep(4000);
          //First page:  Car is already insured or not
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/button[1]")).click();
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          //click next button
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/section/div/div/div/button")).click();
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          //Second page: Owner of car
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/button[2]")).click();
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          //New or used
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]")).click();
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          //Click next song
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/section/div/div/div/button[2]")).click();
          Thread.sleep(1000);


            for (int i =1; i <=3; i++){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/button[3]/div/div[1]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button["+i+"]/div/div[1]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //car registration year data
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("122015");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //click the button to go next
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/section/div/div/div/button[2]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                //Entering Birthday
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("01011992"); 
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.get("https://hello.friday.de/quote/selectVehicle");
                Thread.sleep(1000);

      } 

            for (int i=1; i<=3; i++){
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]/div/div[1]")).click();                             
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button["+i+"]/div/div[1]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("122015");
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              //click the button to go next
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/section/div/div/div/button[2]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              //Entering Birthday
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("01011992"); 
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.get("https://hello.friday.de/quote/selectVehicle");
              Thread.sleep(1000);


          }    


        //----------------------------------------------TestCase:3.1   Brand:Mercedes-Benz Cartype:CLA----------------------------------------------------------//

          for (int i=1; i<=3; i++){
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/button[27]/div/div[1]")).click();                             
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button["+i+"]/div/div[1]")).click();                            
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              //car registration year data
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("122015");
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              //click the button to go next
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/section/div/div/div/button[2]")).click();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              //Entering Birthday
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("01011992"); 
              Thread.sleep(1000);  
              driver.get("https://hello.friday.de/quote/selectVehicle");
              Thread.sleep(1000);


          }

            driver.close();
    }

}
```

**Testng.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.qa.test.FridayTaskTesting"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: My guess is one of the "clicks" is taking more than a second to populate the page.   For this reason, it is always a bad idea to rely on fixed time - far better (and quicker runtime) to use `wait` instead.   What I recommend here is to move all your `Thread.sleep` into a method, and then you can add a `print` statement to find out how far it gets.   Then change that invocation (or all invocations) to do a wait instead.

Comment: @racraman  Tired, still not working.

Comment: If you are executing your code by TestNG so first you removed the main method and write another method name.

Note: for the best way instead of using Thread.sleep(int); you can use explicit wait. Example are given below: 

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("YOUR XPATH")));

kindly use try and catch block for the handling of exceptions due to data or coding errors during program execution.

Comment: @AmitSingh Thank you for the suggestion, It works just after changing the class name :)